How to simulate component unmount and test useEffect cleanup function with React Testing Library
I want to test a cleanup function in the return of useEffect but I'm unable to simulate unmounting a component.
Code I want to test:
useEffect(() => {
      () => clearError(); //I can't cover this line
}, []);

What I have tried
1.
let cleanupFunc;

jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect')
   .mockImplementationOnce(jest.fn())
   .mockImplementationOnce(jest.fn())
    // third useEffect - clear errors
   .mockImplementationOnce((func) => {
      cleanupFunc = func();
   });

render(<Component {...props} />);
      
cleanupFunc();

Error:

TypeError: cleanupFunc is not a function




const { unmount } = render(<Component {...props} />)
unmount()

expect(props.clearError).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

This one is not causing the cleanup function to be executed

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
